# Printing of status message during execution of the bash script

Tags: bash, awk

As a part of my bash routine I am printing some message in terminal regarding status of the workflow. The message in splited into two parts (part 1: begining of the task, part 2: status of its finishing)

```
echo -n "Dataset is being processed ! "; execution of some AWK script; echo " Processing has been COMPLETED!"
```

Here is realisation in bash contained a part of the AWK code:

```
# print pharase 1: initiation of the process
echo -n "Dataset is being rescored.. Please wait"; sleep 0.5 
# this is the process: makedir for the result and execute AWK code to process input file
mkdir ${results}
# Apply the following AWK code on the directory contained input file
while read -r d; do
awk -F, '
}'  "${d}_"*/target_file.csv > "${results}/"${d%%_*}".csv"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*_*_*' | awk -F '[_/]' '!seen[$2]++ {print $2}')
# print pharase 2: finish of the result, which would appear in the terminal near phrase 1
# this will print "COMPLETED" letter-by-letter with the pause of 0.2 sec between each letter
echo -n " C"; sleep 0.2; echo -n "O"; sleep 0.2; echo -n "M"; sleep 0.2; echo -n "P"; sleep 0.2; echo -n "L"; echo -n "E"; sleep 0.2; echo -n "T"; echo -n "E"; sleep 0.2; echo "D!"
```

While executing this script in bash, everything seems to be OK and I have not noticed any problems related to the parts of the code between both 'echo -n' blocks. May such splitting of the status phrase using "echo -n" lead to some bugs of the routine in bash ? Any suggestions for realisation of such status message in bash using another syntax?

Comment: Micro-review - `printf %s` is more portable than `echo -n`.

Comment: Thanks! should I so substitute all ECHO parts of my code to printf when I use it to print some messages in terminal during script execution ? What is the advantae of using printf >&2  ? Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I see very little error-checking in this script.  It's important to know whether `mkdir` succeeded, for example (it certainly won't as it stands, as `results` is never assigned).

We really ought to be quoting variable expansions, to prevent unwanted word-splitting:

```
mkdir "$results" || exit
```

The arbitrary `sleep` values need documenting.  Why do we need to sleep, and how was the duration determined?  Can we wait for something instead?

Not all `echo` implementations accept `-n` option.  To be portable, we should use `printf %s` instead.

The Awk command in the read loop looks like it's corrupted: the closing brace is unmatched.

Since this program is quite chatty, consider printing each file name as it's reached.  Or a fraction complete:

```
readarray -t files \
   < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*_*_*' | awk -F '[_/]' '!seen[$2]++ {print $2}')
for i in ${!files[@]}
do
    d=${files[$i]}
    printf 'Processing (%d/%d)\r' $i ${#files[@]}
    awk -F, $'\n}' "${d}_"*/target_file.csv >"$results/${d%%_*}.csv"
done
```

I don't understand why we have the `!seen[$2]++ {print $2}` in the `find` pipeline - `find` will output each filename exactly once anyway.  Much better to have `find` print just the directories, and zero-terminate them so we're robust enough to handle all possible filenames:

```
readarray -t -d '' files \
   < <(find * -maxdepth 0 -type d -name '*_*_*' -print0)
```